# Play Framework: Global class

Tags: playframework, scope, global

We have a class Global.scala in Play Framework. I was wondering does all the requests share a copy of this class? For example if I were to instantiate an object at this Global.scala

```
val temp = new SomeObject
```

Is above shared among all the requests that comes to the Play? Or does every request have their copy of Global.scala?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `Global` is another singleton object, then yes, all requests will share `Global.temp`, as it gets created when the application is started. Of course, this would obviously not be true for an application distributed across multiple instances.